# Shifting Lever Unit replacement/interchangeability on Shimano 8 speed XT/XTR shifters

Tags: shimano, shifter, replacement

Are the levers/internals interchangeable? Meaning will they all fit the same housing or can I swap one for the other if needed?  Will any 8s XT/XTR shimano 8 speed shifter lever fit any other 8s XT/XTR housing?

Looking at the repair manuals, the part numbers are very similar, and the bolt patterns and housings look very similar.
XTR
([Sl-M950][4], [SL-M951](https://si.shimano.com/api/publish/storage/pdf/en/ev/SL-M951/EV-SL-M951-1705.pdf)) [6BT 9801]
XT
([SL-M739](https://si.shimano.com/api/publish/storage/pdf/en/ev/SL-M739/EV-SL-M739-1638.pdf), [SL-M740](https://si.shimano.com/api/publish/storage/pdf/en/ev/SL-M740/EV-SL-M740-1685.pdf)) [6BA 9801]

(Everything that comes after that seems to be a sealed entity, or made differently)

pdf
[4]:
https://si.shimano.com/api/publish/storage/pdf/en/ev/SL-M950/EV-SL-M950-1629.pdf

Comment: fwiw I'm not sure that Shimano's diagrams tell the whole story; most often something that's shown as a sealed unit is not, it simply means they don't want to provide spare parts for it. As far as this goes, they tend to use the same design for contemporary releases but I wouldn't place bets on anything.

Comment: @thelawnet thanks. I’ll take a closer look when I pop open the shifter for a cleaning.